Handling different flows in data streams in elasticsearch via separate indices
I have been using data streams for my business flow logs, each flow has the different log structure. I have couple of solutions in mind:

Having same structure for each flow and keep stringified version of log object in particular key. For example:

{
    tag: '--ELK--',
    function: '<function name>',
    options: <stringified object>
}

this will inefficient in searching

Having same structure for each flow and keep nested object of log object in particular key. For example:

{
    tag: '--ELK--',
    function: '<function name>',
    options: <JSON object>
}

this will add complexity in writing in the indices as lucene index does not have nested object support.
Is there a way to control the index creation in the data stream in such a way that index could be created as per flow for example: if I have login, signup, and logout flows, in my logs-datastream if I could create different index in the data stream for each flow so that each index would have it's own structure.
Kindly suggest. TIA

An ES datastream is just a convenient way to rotate indices. You can throw any JSON data into a stream, as long as it has a @timestamp field. You can also use nested JSON objects, but ES will index them as a flattened name: {"foo": {"bar": 42}} is indexed as {"foo.bar": 42}. This is efficient, as long as you don't explicitly use the nested type, which is only meaningful in the context of JSON arrays. All of the restrictions you mention sound like older ES versions, or like restrictions from other tools.
